# API Platform Doctrine - Filtering Sub Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have sample cart table

```
class Order
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    private ?int $id = null;

   #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity:Item::class, inversedBy: 'items')]
    private Collection $items;
}
```

And Item entity

```
class Item
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    private ?int $id = null;

   #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity:Order::class, inversedBy: 'orders')]
    private Collection $orders;
}
```

These entities generate automatically the `order_item` many to many table. Suppose that we have sample data inside the `order_item`

| order_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

For order id 1, we have 2 items while the order id 2, we only have 1 item.

The question is, how can I filter those orders that have more than 2 items and display it on api filter response?

Below is my initial custom filter. I'm still thinking of the logic how to achieve it.

```
protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, Operation $operation = null, array $context = []): void
{
    if ($property !== 'totalItems' || empty($value)) {
        return;
    }

    $queryBuilder->select('o.id AS order_id, COUNT(i) AS totalItems')
        ->from(Order::class, "o")->select("o")
        ->leftJoin('o.items', 'i')
        ->groupBy('o.id')

    // Execute the query and get the result
    $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
{
    return [
     'totalItems' => [
         'property' => 'totalItems',
         'type' => 'int',
         'required' => false,
          'description' => 'Get total order items.',
      ],
    ];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to retrive all the entities that have more than one relation to another entity. Here is two samples of how to do this with doctrine :

```
public function test(): void{
    $references = $this->databaseTool->loadFixtures([
        Fixture::class
    ])->getReferenceRepository();

    $compteRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(CompteUtilisateur::class); //Your entity here
    //Because findAll return an array and filter() is only applicable on collections
    $allComptes = new ArrayCollection($compteRepository->findAll());
//Result using repository
    $comptesAvecPlusDuneRelation = $allComptes->filter(function (CompteUtilisateur $compteUtilisateur){
        return count($compteUtilisateur->getRelCompteCarteJeune()) > 1;
    });
//Result using query builder (using 'having' is always a must)
    $memesComptesAvecPlusDuneRelation = $compteRepository->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->innerJoin('c.relCompteCarteJeune', 'ccj')
        ->groupBy('c.id')
        ->having('COUNT(ccj) > 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

I strongly advice you to make unit tests (using phpunit) and using a debugger (xdebug) in your IDE.
Fixtures allows you to load your database with entities you want. It's purged after each test making it the most efficiently possible to test your code.
You can use LiipTestFixtureBundle and DoctrineFixtureBundle to achieve this.

- https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/the-fast-track/en/17-tests.html#writing-unit-tests
- https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/tree/2.x
- https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html
- https://xdebug.org/wizard

Within your code it should be like this i think :

```
$orderRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Order::class);
$allOrders = new ArrayCollection($orderRepository->findAll());
//Result using repository
    $ordersWithMoreThanOneRelation = $allOrders->filter(function (Order $order){
        return count($order->getItems()) > 1;
    });
//Result using query builder (using 'having' is always a must)
    $sameOrdersWithMoreThanOneRelation = $orderRepository->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select('o')
        ->innerJoin('o.items', 'items')
        ->groupBy('o.id')
        ->having('COUNT(items) > 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```